# How can I tell what the date_diff duration is?

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I have the following code:

```
$sStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['sStart']));
$sEnd   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['sEnd']));

$sStartDate = new DateTime($sStart);
$sEndDate   = new DateTime($sEnd);

$diff = date_diff($sStartDate, $sEndDate, true);

$dur = $diff->format('%h:%i');
```

`$row['sStart']` and `$row['sEnd']` are `datetime`s from a MySQL database.

How can I tell if `$diff` is over 24 hours long?

Comment: Check the examples in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: you can use the dateadd()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$diff` is of type [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

I think that this will give you the number of hours using the result of the date_diff:

```
$hours = ($diff->days * 24) + $diff->h;

if ($hours > 24) {
    // etc ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 24 hours is 1 day, you can use the `%a` modifier to the [`DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) call to calculate the number of days the interval crosses:

```
$sStartDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-05-13 21:56:00');
$sEndDate   = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-05-14 21:56:01');

$diff = date_diff($sStartDate, $sEndDate, true);

$days = $diff->format('%a');
if (1 <= $days) {
    echo '24 hours or more.';
} else {
    echo 'less than 24 hours.';
}
```

[See it live.](https://3v4l.org/7k3js)